# Python YAML reader with inter-dependencies

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

I have a YAML config for a framework. In order to me to process the list in order, I wanted to know what is depend on(basically dependent tree structure). Below is an example, where processing "post" segment is depend on "pre"."output".

The default YAML python reader just reads in order. I need to establish dependency and process in order of dependency. anybody worked on this scenario in Python?

```
jobs:
  - job: "post"
    source:
      flight: "pre_output"
    transform: "transform2"
    output: "post_output"
  - job: "pre"
    source:
      flight: "flight"
    transform: "transform1"
    output: "pre_output"
```

Comment: "The default Python YAML reader" Python doesn't have one

Comment: Yes, it has to be custom built

Comment: Parse the whole file, then create a list and put every step in the right order.

Comment: Excellent, this is what am looking for.